# Selecting random array to print out! How can i print out random array with alle the data including the image? When user clicks on button

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

Click here

```
    <script>
    
        var luckBtn = document.getElementById('luck');  //getting the button
        
        //array containing information about different profiles
        var randomProfileArray= [                                               

        ["Jonas", 23, "Væren", "Ja", "images/man1.jpg"], //[0] //first array
        ["Abdi", 24, "Tyren", "Ja", "images/man2.jpg"], //[1] //second array
        ["Qais", 27, "Tvillingen", "Ja", "images/man3.jpg"], //[2] //third array
        ["Lola", 29, "Tyren", "Ja", "images/woman1.jpg"], [3] //fourth array
  
                            ]; 
    //Array is containing:    (Name, age, starsymbol, compatibility, yes, image)//
```

//I am very beginner in js, but i want to use the math.floor math.random method to print out a random array/profile when user clicks on the button provided in the html. I was wondering how and if i can use the for loop here? And how can i use a function?

```
    </script>
```

Comment: <label>Click here</label>
              <input id="luck" type="button" value="i'll go with the luck">

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like that:

```
<button onclick=randomArray()>click on me </button>
```

and inside script:

```
<script>
function randomArray() { // your code here }
</script>
```